# How do I refer to a container by name in docker stack?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to deploy a simple Django/Postgress app using a docker-compose file on a docker swarm (the two containers are running on different VMs). However, I when I try establishing the connection between the two using container names (e.g. to set up Django's connection to the database) I cannot seem to use the container names.  For example, if I try to run migrations from the Django container, the host name of the database container is not recognised.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "random"
      POSTGRES_USER: "random"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "random"
  app:
    image: "app_server"
    build:
      context: ./app_server
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: 'psql://random:random@db:5432/random'
```

and this is the database connection config in Django's settings.py

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

        'NAME': 'random',

        'USER': 'random',

        'PASSWORD': 'random',

        'HOST': 'db',

        'PORT': '5432',

    }

}
```

Is there a way in which I can make the Django app automatically aware of the IP of the database service?

I tried using the "name:" parameter in the service configuration, but the didn't work.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: if both Vm's are in the same swarm then the hostname of the database is `db`, so basically it works the same way it works when you run docker-compose localy

Comment: vms are a part of the same swarm, but still doesn't work